# Reading TwinCAT variables are not correct (TwinCAT 3 - C# Framework 4.7.2)

Tags: c#, read-write, twincat

I use struct in BeckHoff to read variables. When struct has data variables, I can read vaiables in c#. But when Struct has an function block, I can't read variables correctly.
But I can write in any case.

1: I can read these variables on C# (I can write);

```
TYPE AxisStruct :
STRUCT
    EnablePower         : BOOL;         // Enable
    ExecuteHome         : BOOL;         // Home
    HomeSwitch          : BOOL;         // Home Switch
    ExecuteReset        : BOOL;         // Reset
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE
```

2: I can't read Axis variables correctly on C#; (I can write)

```
TYPE fbAxis :
STRUCT
    Axis        : fbServo;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE
```

// fbServo Function Block:

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK fbServo
VAR_INPUT
        
    EnablePower         : BOOL;  
    ExecuteHome         : BOOL;  
    HomeSwitch          : BOOL;  
    ExecuteReset        : BOOL;
END_VAR
VAR_OUTPUT
    ActualPos           : REAL;
    ActualVel           : REAL;
    HasJob              : BOOL;
    HasError            : BOOL;
END_VAR
VAR
   AxisName             : Axis_Ref; 
END_VAR
```

3: MAIN in BeckHoff;

```
PROGRAM MAIN
VAR
    Rotary          : fbAxis;
END_VAR

Rotary.Axis();
```

4:I try to read on C# like this;

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    beckhoffClient.NotificationReceived += BeckhoffClient_NotificationReceived;
    RotaryAxis = Get_NotficationHandleForPages("MAIN.Rotary.Axis", 100, 200, typeof(fbServo));
}

public int RotaryAxis = 0;
    public struct fbServo 
    {

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
        public bool EnablePower;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
        public bool ExecuteHome;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
        public bool HomeSwitch;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
        public bool ExecuteReset;
        
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]
        public float ActualPos;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]
        public float ActualVel;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
        public bool HasJob;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
        public bool HasError;
    }
    fbServo Axiss = new fbServo();

    private void BeckhoffClient_NotificationReceived(object sender, AdsNotificationExEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NotificationHandle == RotaryAxis)
        {
            Axiss = (fbServo)e.Value;
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                EnablePowerText.Text = Axiss.EnablePower.ToString();
                ExecuteHometext.Text = Axiss.ExecuteHome.ToString();
                HomePostext.Text = Axiss.HomePos.ToString();
                HomeSwitchtext.Text = Axiss.HomeSwitch.ToString();
                ExecuteResettext.Text = Axiss.ExecuteReset.ToString();

                ActualPostext.Text = Axiss.ActualPos.ToString();
                ActualVeltext.Text = Axiss.ActualVel.ToString();
                HasJobtext.Text = Axiss.HasJob.ToString();
                HasErrortext.Text = Axiss.HasError.ToString();

            }));
        }
    }
```

5: I can write like this;

```
    private void TestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BeckHoffWriteVal("MAIN.Rotary.Axis.EnablePower", true);
    }
```

When I use function block in struct (number 2), my all boolean values set 'TRUE' and my all float values (real variable in beckhoff) set '0' (picture in below) when I change the order of MarshalAs and its variable, some of float values changes (corrupt data).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen below, writing and reading is possible (I used my Python ads client implementation).

Please try and read a variable directly instead of using the notification mechanism. If that works try the notification mechanism.
Also try to read a simple variable instead of the entire structure.

Note that the system must know how to convert the bytes received over ads from the plc in to variable(s).
For "MAIN.Rotary.Axis" the plc returns for instance 1128 bytes; '\x98\n\x8em\x0f\xbb\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc3\xf5H@\x00'....

Also note that "MAIN.Rotary.Axis" holds much more than you defined. How does the system know what to pick from the data to write in to which of the few variables?

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for your comment @owillebo, I cant see any bytes on values when I use breakpoint. "MAIN.Rotary.Axis" holds much more than I defined. I changed int as any variables, nothing changed. I tried witout INotificationChanged and I tried calling variables step by step but nothing changed. I only get boolean variables as 'TRUE', the others as '0'

Answer (score 0):

You aren't really telling what is the problem. Do you get an error or is the data corrupted?

I'm guessing you have corrupted data. The problem might be the pack-mode, which means how bytes are aligned in memory. Usually TwinCAT system and your PC have different alignments. This means that there *might* be empty padding bytes between variables. It depends on variable sizes so sometimes it works without any hassle.

You should add the `{attribute 'pack_mode' := '1'}` pragma above all STRUCT definitions in PLC that you read/write with C#:

```
{attribute 'pack_mode' := '1'} 
TYPE ST_MyStruct:  
STRUCT 
    //variables here normally
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE
```

And in C# side, add the following above struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public struct ST_MyStruct
{
  //Same variables here with corresponding types
}
```

Now the data should be 1:1 in memory. However I haven't tested with function blocks.

And one another problem: If the struct/fb is not made by you, like `Axis_Ref`, you can't change the pack mode. You need to create your own data struct for C# and copy values there in the PLC.

By the way, you dont need `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]`, the float should work fine as-is.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The problem is, I get all boolean variables as 'TRUE' and anothers as 'NaN' or different values like "3,573311E-43" . 
I use Axis_Ref, MC_HOME, MC_RESET .. etc functions of Beckhoff.

I tried your solution but nothing changed.

Comment: I get values very different and meaningless. all is 'TRUE' here is picture about this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlzK0.png

Comment: By the way, I can read values clearly when I don't use function blocks. But when I use function block instead, I can write values on variables but I can't read them.

Comment: You can't change pack-mode of beckhoff's function blocks. So you need to remove them from data read using C#. That problem with float looks just like wrong byte alignment (pack-mode). Writing works as you can always read/write single non-structural variables as pack-mode doesn't affect them.

Comment: So your suggestion is removing function blocks in struct? 
I chose fb. because I have many servos to be controlled. I created a fb. for avoid code complexity. Other wise I have to write many of variables for each servo fb.(mc_home, jog,power etc.)

Comment: Yes, that's my suggestion. Unless you find a better way.